# Unable to access Parcelable in Fragment arguments (Error: 'arguments' is a mutable property)

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

How to properly access arguments in a Fragment with kotlin?

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
  if(arguments!=null){
    detail = Parcels.unwrap(arguments.getParcelable(DETAIL_KEY))
  }
}
```

but the compiler rightly complains with this error:

> Error: Smart cast to 'Bundle' is impossible, because 'arguments' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time

I am wondering: is there an elegant way to handle this besides using the `!!` operator?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val arguments = arguments
detail = arguments?.let { args -> Parcels.unwrap(args.getParcelable(DETAIL_KEY)) }
```

Comment: Yes, this does work. (even with the question updated) but I don't like declaring a `val` (especially with the same name) only to do that. Is that the common practice?

Comment: I do it surprisingly often.

Comment: Actually, it just came to my mind that we could use `it` to avoid the assignment, like this: `arguments?.let { detail  = Parcels.unwrap(it.getParcelable(DETAIL_KEY)) }`

Comment: That's true. Although I prefer to name it to something else like for example `args`. You need the `val` assignment if you use args in an `if(!= null` statement

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I was stupid and I could just do:

```
detail = Parcels.unwrap(arguments?.getParcelable(DETAIL_KEY))
```

without any complaint by the compiler.